# how to get git image from the git hub when I only have a specific file's link?

Tags: git, github-api

I found a useful sample file at
https://github.com/SayCV/rtems-example-sparc-leon/blob/master/rtems-spi-sdcard.c
I cound get this sample file (by pressing 'raw' button and downloading the .c file) but I don't know how to get the whole git image.
Somebody please help!

ADD : For information, this command worked for me.
"git clone github.com/SayCV/rtems-example-sparc-leon.git"
see my comment to ckruczek's comment below.

Answer (score 2):

The whole git image? I may could image what you want to achieve:

```
git clone git@github.com:SayCV/rtems-example-sparc-leon.git
```

And you are ready to go.

Comment: I tried you suggestion and got : 
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ckim/rtems-example-sparc-leon/.git/
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
What's wrong?

Comment: Well git is telling you whats wrong. You might did not have setup a ssh key for your github account, or might even not have github account. You could also use the HTTPS link to clone the repo.

Comment: "git clone https://github.com/SayCV/rtems-example-sparc-leon.git"
worked for me. But I logged into github before doing this, so I'm not sure it's relevant to the success. (after logging in, I searched for rtems-example-sparc-leon and in the page found, I could see http clone URL on the github web page). Thanks.